# The difference between Mono.just(1) vs. Flux.just(1)

Tags: project-reactor

I wonder, is there any difference in behavior/guarantees between the `MonoJust` and `FluxJust` created with exactly one argument?

From the source code of the Reactor Core 3.3.7 I am able to see that the former one is using the `Operators#ScalarSubscription` as its subscription object, while the latter one uses its private `WeakScalarSubscription`.

The only difference between these two is that `ScalarSubscription` has this `volatile int once` thing (a counter) defined and checked on each method call and somewhat ensures the `onComplete()` is called exactly once. At the same time, `WeakScalarSubscription` uses the `boolean terminado` thing (a non-volatile flag) for the same purposes, but without the "exactly once" guarantees for `onComplete()` call.

Using `volatile` in Java has its price, which is payed off e.g. when one creates a lot of these things (with `Mono.just(1)` or `Flux.just(1)`) in the highly-concurrent client code. (As we do in our project inside the `flatMap` that runs in parallel on a dedicated thread pool.)

There's no class javadoc for `MonoJust`, so I wonder if my assumptions are correct: that the only difference is that `FluxJust` may send the completion signal more than once in some circumstances — and that's it? Or are there other subtle differences?

Comment: If you look through you'll see a few subtle differences concerning the Operators, e.g in `clear()` and `cancel()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the biggest difference is how you use `Flux` and `Mono`. `Mono` emits one item or error and then completes, whereas `Flux` can emit more than one element, error, and then completion signal.

`just()` methods are meant to evaluate one element (or `vararg` variant for `Flux`) and return it immediately. I can imagine cases when `Flux` with only one element is returned.

Comment: Think they are asking more about the specific implementations of `Flux.just(singleElement)` vs `Mono.just(singleElement)` since the code for both is very similar